# Exact Difference between Oracle Client and Oracle Database

Tags: oracle

Can someone please explain the exact Difference between Oracle Client and Oracle Database?

Answer (score 3):

Oracle Client Software is a package of components such as SQLNet and ASO (Advanced Security Option). SQLNet is remote data access software that enables communication with Oracle databases in a distributed computing environment. Specifically, SQL*Net lets clients, such as Macintosh or Windows computers with database applications, communicate with servers containing Oracle databases.It also lets servers with Oracle databases communicate with other servers with Oracle databases.

Oracle Client Software is intended for applications that connect to Oracle databases.

With Oracle10 Oracle introduces an so called Instant Client which needs no installation with the Oracle Universal Installer. It is sufficient to copy it into the path of the user.

Comment: And Oracle database? How's it defined?

Answer (score 3):

A database server is the Oracle software managing a database, and a client is an application that requests information from a server.
 Each computer in a network is a node that can host one or more databases. Each node in a distributed database system can act as a client, a server, or both, depending on the situation.